# Python SAML authentication

Tags: python, saml, onelogin

I'm trying to build a SAML authentication mechanism in Python using the OneLogin module, but I can't even get started. Trying from the example code provided in the docs, I can't even load the package.

This works:

```
import onelogin
```

but this gets a ModuleNotFoundError:

```
>>> from onelogin.saml2.auth import OneLogin_Saml2_Auth
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'onelogin.saml2'
```

Answer (score 0):

I only managed to get this working on a Linux machine, so hope you're not on windows. Here's what worked for me.

I had to do a seperate install of hte xmlsec-library first:

```
apt-get install xmlsec1 openssl python-lxml libxmlsec1 libxmlsec1-dev
```

and then I was able to

```
pip install python3-saml
```

and there were no complains anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install Xmlsec first and then python3-saml but if you are on Windows, Xmlsec has some issues but as with python 3.6 and below the problem is solved. Use this link to download the wheel file for your python version https://github.com/mehcode/python-xmlsec/releases

Install the wheel file using

```
pip install <wheel_file_name>
```

As with Python 3.7, the only way out is to install xmlsec on a Linux machine as it is not yet supported on Windows.